# While Fine Tuning the Query in Java Program, Face an issue using SubQuery instead of Join

Tags: sql, db2

### EXISTING QUERY:

```
SELECT   
 SUBSTR(B.C_TYP, 1, 4)                        
,SUBSTR(B.X_DESC, 1, 25)                      
,SUBSTR(A.C_TYP, 5, 4)                        
,SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 1, 25)                      
,SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 82, 11) FROM     M.MASCTAB A, M.MASCTAB B WHERE    
       A.I_PLT = ?
AND    A.N_TBL = ?                                
AND    A.C_TYP LIKE ?                          
AND    A.I_PLT = B.I_PLT                            
AND    SUBSTR(A.C_TYP, 1, 4) = SUBSTR(B.C_TYP, 1, 4)
AND    SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 81, 1) = 'W'                
AND    B.N_TBL = 'DEPTC'                            
ORDER    BY A.C_TYP
```

### MODIFIED QUERY:

```
SELECT 

(SELECT SUBSTR(C_TYP, 1, 4)
FROM M.MASCTAB
WHERE I_PLT = A.I_PLT
AND N_TBL = 'DEPTC'
AND LEFT(C_TYP, 4) = LEFT(A.C_TYP, 4) 
)
,(SELECT SUBSTR(X_DESC, 1, 25) 
FROM M.MASCTAB 
WHERE I_PLT = A.I_PLT 
AND N_TBL = 'DEPTC' 
AND LEFT(C_TYP, 4) = LEFT(A.C_TYP, 4) 
),SUBSTR(A.C_TYP, 5, 4) 
,SUBSTR(A.X_DESC,1, 25) 
,SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 82, 11) 
FROM M.MASCTAB A
WHERE A.I_PLT = ? 
AND A.N_TBL = ? 
AND A.C_TYP LIKE ? 
AND SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 81, 1) = 'W' 
ORDER BY A.C_TYP 
WITH UR
```

After Optimizing the Query, with exact result set, Faced issue after deploying the code.
Error _jspService errorclass java.lang.NullPointerException

What would be issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with your `select (select ...), (select ...), .... From ....)`. The query will only be successful as long as your two subqueries return exactly 1 or 0 results.

Looking at your initial query, it looks very simple or innocent. There are a few things you might be able to optimize though.

1. `A.C_TYP LIKE ?` - the like operator is dangerous. This can tank the performance of your query. From your program feeding that query try to avoid constructs where '%' is at the beginning of the string.
2. Do you use an index? - Create one that for I_PLT, N_TBL (one index that contains both values)
3. consider creating new columns in your table for that contains the value of SUBSTR(C_TYP, 1, 4) and SUBSTR(X_DESC, 81, 1) = 'W'. You will be storing redundant data but you don't need to calculate the values over and over again. You should create a trigger that fires for every insert and update to fill the two columns for your search. This will increase performance if you read more than you write the table.
4. <strike>Temporary tables</strike>  Common table Expressions might be an option too. see query below. (Disclaimer: Query is not tested for performance and for correctness of syntax)

---

```
with temp_table as 
   (select C_TYP, X_DESC, I_PLT, N_TBL, SUBSTR(C_TYP, 1, 4) as join_key
      from M.MASCTAB) 
select B.join_key,
       SUBSTR(B.X_DESC, 1, 25),
       SUBSTR(A.C_TYP, 5, 4),
       SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 1, 25),
       SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 82, 11) 
FROM temp_table A inner join temp_table B on A.join_key=B.join_key
WHERE  A.I_PLT = ?
AND    A.N_TBL = ?                                
AND    A.C_TYP LIKE ?                          
AND    A.I_PLT = B.I_PLT                            
AND    SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 81, 1) = 'W'                
AND    B.N_TBL = 'DEPTC'                            
ORDER    BY A.C_TYP
```

Comment: This is an example of a common table expression, not a temporary table, fortunately.  True temporary tables are often a poor performance choice unless they will be used in multiple statements.

Comment: sorry, took the name of the SQL cookbook. However, of course you are right, that strictly spoken, it is not a temporary table.

Comment: one reason temp tables are frequently a poor choice, and using CTE's instead... http://iprodeveloper.com/database/sensible-approach-multi-step-db2-i-query-solutions

Comment: Using 'real' temporary tables (`DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE`)  is in most cases detrimental for performance. I would only consider using these temporary tables if I need the intermediate results in different following queries (e.g. for creating several reports) so I don't need to calculate the intermediate data several times. However, what I meant was CTE (common table expression), which might help in this situation. I updated the answer to reflect the correct terminology.

Comment: Hi Basically Am fine tuning the query to reduce the COST*RATE and SU*RATE which helps in increase in performance. But as I execute the Query with "WITH", the COST*RATE increased than the earlier one. Please suggest me a optimized query. The Modified query which I mentioned though reduces the performance tremendously and the result set same with exisiting one, It throws an error. Please suggest on this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I wanted to reduce the MIPS through reducing the COST*RATE and SU*RATE when I ran this query, I found that the cost hitted to the maximum of 139081.632812$ whereas my earlier query was in hundreds $$.

Comment: It looks like your test data and your production data are different. Therefore your query bombs in prod and not in your test env. The original query is pretty simple giving the query optimizer lots of freedom. Long story short, look at the database for optimizations not to the query. So check for indexes, table partitions, precalculating relevant values (extra columns), etc. Maybe you only need an reorg in prod to improve speed. It's not always the queries fault that it is slow. Sometimes the database needs some TLC.

Comment: @Peter Schuetze Hi Peter, I do agree with your point on indexing, already this query is indexed and right now per query fetch its costing around 25$ which needs to be reduced as per the requirement and this particular query is fetched more than a lakh time per day. Quick Reply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using DB2 LUW, i, or z/OS?

Comment: Can you post the indexes that are defined on that table? If that table is read way more than written too, then consider adding more columns (point2 in my answer). This way you already precalculate the substring and don't need to do that for every row. Especially `SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 81, 1) = 'W'` hurts, because you can't use an index for it.

Comment: The ideal indexes may depend upon the distribution of values in the relevant columns.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze indexing capabilities are server dependent, and i have not seen an indication yet from Guru which DB2 platform is being used.

Comment: even without indexes, he should be able to increase the speed of the table by precalculating some of his filtering options.

Comment: Agreed, although the index might precalculate for him, if he can index over expressions (DB2 for i or z/OS)

Comment: I just found some info in ibms info center for DB2 LUW regarding performance of queries. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0054702.html -- specifically http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0055217.html talks about expression and how to avoid them. Generated Columns are the key (what I suggest in point 3).

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to use Common Table Expressions, but don't quite have the syntax down.  Based on what your original query says, and keeping the structure of your modified query, it looks like your modified query should say something like this:

```
with A as
( SELECT I_PLT
        ,N_TBL
        ,SUBSTR(C_TYP, 1, 4) MAIN_TYPE
        ,SUBSTR(C_TYP, 5, 4) SUB_TYPE
        ,SUBSTR(X_DESC, 1, 25) X_DESC_PT1
        ,SUBSTR(X_DESC,82, 11) X_DESC_PT2
    FROM M.MASCTAB 
    WHERE I_PLT = ? 
      AND N_TBL = ? 
      AND C_TYP LIKE ? 
      AND SUBSTR(A.X_DESC, 81, 1) = 'W' 
), B as 
( SELECT I_PLT
        ,SUBSTR(C_TYP, 1, 4)     MAIN_TYPE
        ,SUBSTR(X_DESC, 1, 25)   DESC_PT1
FROM M.MASCTAB
WHERE N_TBL = 'DEPTC'
) 
SELECT B.MAIN_TYPE
      ,B.DESC_1
      ,A.SUB_TYPE
      ,A.DESC_1
      ,A.DESC_2
  FROM A
  JOIN B
          ON A.I_PLT   = B.I_PLT                            
     AND A.MAIN_TYPE = B.MAIN_TYPE 
  ORDER BY MAIN_TYPE,SUB_TYPE 
WITH UR
```

Comment: Hi Basically Am fine tuning the query to reduce the COST*RATE and SU*RATE which helps in increase in performance. But as I execute the Query with "WITH", the COST*RATE increased  than the earlier one. Please suggest me a optimized query. The Modified query which I mentioned though reduces the performance tremendously and the result set same with exisiting one, It throws an error. Please suggest on this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question does not mention these fields. Your names are cryptic enough that I is hard to be sure exactly what is going on, nor did you mention any requirements for the query.

Comment: What OS is your DB2 server running on, and what version of DB2?

Comment: sorry about not mentioning the index. Current version is db2v9.

Comment: I figured out that the issue is due to the NULL Resultant for first two columns, Could anyone help me how to suppress this NULL Value?

Comment: Sorry, which column names on what part of which query, mine?

Comment: `COALESCE(x,y)` is probably the most portable function to return the value of y if x is null.